# Call a function from view Laravel 5

Tags: function, laravel-5, call

I am working on a Laravel Project and I need some help

I am passing data from AdsController.php

```
$ads = Ads::all(); 
return view('Ads/index', enter code herecompact('ads','users'));
```

But in the Same view I want to get data from other tables

```
@foreach ($ads as $ad) 
$ad->id // Now from this Id I want to get the user's name and picture so..
{{AdsControlller::get_user_img($ad->id)}}
@endforeach
```

in The AdsController I have the function

```
Public static function get_user_img($id){
$user = User::find($id);
return $user-img;
}
```

But I keep getting this error 
Class 'AdsController' not Found !

Comment: Inject all the data that your view needs in your AdsController. 
But most of all, read the documentation and experiment with the examples first. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the class by its fully qualified name, including namespaces. If `AdsController` is in `App\Http\Controllers` (might be different for you), then:

```
{{\App\Http\Controllers\AdsController::get_user_img($ad->id)}}
```

(The leading slash indicates to start at the global namespace.)

Comment: Yes Thank You :) 
It worked :)